# Automatic Import/Graphing of Text Files in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, import

I run a machine which puts out multiple text files which I plot, I have a VBA script which can import all of the files I want to plot from a folder and puts them on their own sheet. I was wondering if there was a way in which I could automatically have them plotted when they are imported as well? I need a separate graph for each pair of tests. That is I have "Test A-1" and "Test A-2" which are plotted against each other, "Test B-1" and "Test B-2" on a new graph etc. Sorry if this is confusing, I am still pretty new to VBA and would love a tool like this to make my life a bit easier. I have included my code which does all the importing below. Each text file (which is just data for a x-y scatter plot) is then given its own sheet, with the data in columns A and B. Apologies in advance for the terrible formatting, I didn't write it!

```
Sub ImportTextToExcel()
'UpdatebyExtendoffice20180911
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim xToBook As Workbook
Dim xStrPath As String
Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
Dim xFile As String
Dim xFiles As New Collection
Dim I As Long
Dim xIntRow As Long
Dim xFNum, xFArr As Long
Dim xStrValue As String
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xArr

Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder"
If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
End If
If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
If Right(xStrPath, 1) <> "\" Then xStrPath = xStrPath & "\"
xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "*.txt")
If xFile = "" Then
MsgBox "No files found", vbInformation
Exit Sub
End If
Do While xFile <> ""
xFiles.Add xFile, xFile
xFile = Dir()
Loop
Set xToBook = ThisWorkbook
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If xFiles.Count > 0 Then

For I = 1 To xFiles.Count
Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(xStrPath & xFiles.Item(I))
xWb.Worksheets(1).Copy after:=xToBook.Sheets(xToBook.Sheets.Count)

ActiveSheet.Name = xWb.Name

xWb.Close False
xIntRow = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
For xFNum = 1 To xIntRow
Set xRg = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & xFNum)
xArr = Split(xRg.Text, " ")
If UBound(xArr) > 0 Then
For xFArr = 0 To UBound(xArr)
If xArr(xFArr) <> "" Then
xRg.Value = xArr(xFArr)
Set xRg = xRg.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1)
End If
Next
End If
Next
Next
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: "Apologies in advance for the terrible formatting" - you know *you* can fix it, right? So we don't have to try to read it like that?

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ImportTextToExcel()
    'UpdatebyExtendoffice20180911
    Dim xWb As Workbook, xToBook As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim xFile As String, xStrPath As String, xStrValue As String
    Dim xRg As Range, cht As Chart
    Dim xFiles As New Collection
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' choose folder
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select a folder"
       If .Show = -1 Then
           xStrPath = .SelectedItems(1)
       End If
    End With
    If xStrPath = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Right(xStrPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        xStrPath = xStrPath & "\"
    End If

    ' build collection of text files
    xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "*.txt")
    Do While xFile <> ""
        xFiles.Add xFile, xFile
        xFile = Dir()
    Loop
    If xFiles.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files found", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' import data
    Set xToBook = ThisWorkbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To xFiles.Count
        
        ' import data into new sheet
        Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(xStrPath & xFiles.Item(i))
        xWb.Worksheets(1).Copy after:=xToBook.Sheets(xToBook.Sheets.Count)
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
        ws.Name = xWb.Name
        xWb.Close False

        ' split on space
        Set xRg = ws.Range("A1")
        xRg.CurrentRegion.TextToColumns Destination:=xRg.Cells(1, 1), _
                          DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                          ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, _
                          Space:=True, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1))
        
        ' create chart
        Set cht = ws.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
        With cht
            .ChartType = xlXYScatter
            .SetSourceData Source:=xRg.CurrentRegion
        End With
        
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox xFiles.Count & " files imported", vbInformation
End Sub
```